# Que significa la operación ^=

Tags: c#, algoritmos, operador

Estaba pasando un tiempo en codewars, y dí con un ejercicio que pedía:

> Dado un array, encuentra el `int` que aparece un número impar de
>   veces.
>
> Siempre habrá un solo número entero que aparece un número impar de
>   veces.

Lo resolví usando `GroupBy` pero al ver todas las respuestas, una era la siguiente:

```
public static int find_it(int[] seq)
{
    int found = 0;

    foreach (var num in seq)
    {
        found ^= num;
    }

    return found;
}
```

Caso de ejemplo

```
var result ; find_it(new[] { 20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5 })
//result vale 5.
```

Me llamó la atención, porque nunca había usado el operador `^=` por lo que me puse a depurar e intentar entenderlo, pero sin éxito.

No entiendo de que manera en la variable `found` termina, precisamente, el número que aparece una cantidad impar de veces.

¿Alguien podría explicarme como funciona?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

El operador ^ es el operador binario del OR exclusivo. En el caso de comparación entre enteros (como el tuyo) compara bit a bit los valores y devuelve 0 si los bits son iguales o 1 si son diferentes. En tu caso lo utiliza junto al operador de asignación, es decir:

```
found ^= num;
```

Termina siendo lo mismo que:

```
found = found ^ num;
```

En tu vector vas a tener un solo numero que se repite un número impar de veces, el resto siempre seran repeticiones pares. Pongamos un ejemplo con un vector chico asi se entiende:

```
int found = 0;

foreach (var num in seq)
{
    found ^= num;
}

find_it(new[] { 2, 5, 1, 1, 2 })
```

Como dije antes, en enteros la comparación es bit a bit.
En la primera iteración compara el 0 con el 2, en binario:

```
000 ^ 010
```

El resultado será:

```
010
```

En el segunda iteración el resultado anterior con el 5:

```
010 ^ 101
```

Resultado:

```
111
```

Ahora sigue un 1:

```
111 ^ 001
```

Resultado:

```
110
```

Cuarta iteración nuevamente 1:

```
110 ^ 001
```

Resultado:

```
111
```

Y la ultima iteración el 2:

```
111 ^ 010
```

Resultado final:

```
101
```

Que en decimal es el 5, justamente el único número que se repite un número impar de veces.

Para que se entienda mejor, cuando se hace un OR Exclusivo entre 2 valores iguales, el resultado siempre será 0. Y cuando comparás 0 con X, el resultado siempre será X. Entonces, los valores de repeticiones pares se cancelaran siempre entre ellos dejando como resultado 0. Al final este cero se comparará con el unico valor que te sobra (por ser repetición impar), y por ende el resultado será ese valor. Esto es siempre así, sin importar el orden de dichos valores.

Te dejo la documentación oficial de dicho operador:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator